# How can I import a .3ds file into JMonkeyEngine 3?

Tags: 3d, jmonkeyengine

I am trying to import an animated character body (with skeleton) from 3D Studio Max to JMonkeyEngine 3, but while we succeeded at importing some animations, we cannot seem to export the skeleton to `.skeleton.xml` using OgreXML format. Since OgreXML seems to be the favored way to import models into JME, we dropped `.obj` files and such.

How can I get a `.3ds` file into my JMonkeyEngine project?

Comment: You're right, it is more suitable here. Please ensure that you don't just duplicate a question over multiple Stack Exchange sites though - it's called cross-posting, and it's discouraged because it reduces the usefulness of the site. I've requested the SO topic be closed because it's been cross-posted (and because _it belongs here_, so don't worry that you're losing anything - if anything it would've been moved here eventually).

Answer (score 1):

JMonkeyEngine [does not natively support](http://jmonkeyengine.org/features/asset-pipeline/) `.3ds` as of this writing. Your best bet is going to be to wrangle your `.3ds` models into a format it *does* support, such as `.blend` or `.obj`.

If you don't need the animations, I'd go with `.obj`. Even though it may not be "favored," it sounds like it will work, and that's more important.

You could also [import the Max file into Blender and then save it](http://www.blender3darchitect.com/2010/04/blender-2-50-how-to-import-and-export-from-3ds-max-2010/), since the engine's asset pipeline supports `.blend`.

It appears that [as of the beginning of January](http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/2013/01/3ds-and-collada-import/), support for importing `.3ds` was added, but it's unclear whether this was only a community-build set of scripts or if it will eventually make it into the real product.